# ADDC versus ADD

Tags: assembly, 8051

I'm trying to figure out the difference between `ADDC` and `ADD` instructions for 8051 microcontrollers.

> Description: `ADD` and `ADDC` both add the value operand to the value of the Accumulator, leaving the resulting value in the Accumulator. The value operand is not affected. `ADD` and `ADDC` function identically except that `ADDC` adds the value of operand as well as the value of the Carry flag whereas `ADD` does not add the Carry flag to the result.

How does ADDC "add the carry flag to the result"? The result is in the accumulator, how does it add a carry flag to it?

Currently, as I see it, here is how they work:

```
MOV A, #0xFF
ADD A, #0x01
```

The result of this is `A = 0x01` and `C = 1`

With ADDC,

```
MOV A, #0xFF
ADDC A, #0x01
```

The result of this is `A = 0x01` and `C = 1`

Maybe my tests are not right or something. Can someone explain the difference between ADD and ADDC?

Comment: "Adds the carry flag" simply means "increments if the carry flag was set"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the value of the carry flag *before* the addition that is relevant. `ADDC` includes it in the sum while `ADD` doesn't.

`ADDC X, Y` stores X + Y + Carry in `X`.

`ADD` only stores X + Y in `X`.

The purpose of this is to allow chained addition on multi-word "big integers." This is accomplished by adding each word from least to most significant. Using ADDC ensures that carries from previous additions are carried to the next-higher significant word.

Answer (score 2):

In each of your cases, do a subsequent:

```
ADD A, #0x01
```

and:

```
ADDC A, #0x01
```

In the first case, you should see `A = 0x02` and in the second `A = 0x03`. When the carry flag was set, `ADDC` will add `1` for the carry flag in addition to the value you are adding to `A`.